# How to make this to just speak once even though you have multiple letter/number in the input field(rfid code)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever I tap the RFID which has 10 character code, the code keeps on looping 10 times, how can I make it speak just once then cancel the next ones?

```
  $(function(){
  if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
      var $voicelist = $('#voices');

      if($voicelist.find('#voices').length == 0) {
        speechSynthesis.getVoices().forEach(function(voice, index) {
          var $option = $('#voices')
          .val(index)
          .html(voice.name + (voice.default ? ' (default)' :''));

          $voicelist.append($option);
        });

      }
    }

    $('#rfid').keypress(function(){
      var text = document.getElementById("res").innerHTML; 
      var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      var voices = $('#voices');
      msg.voice = voices[$('#voices').val()];
      msg.rate = 10 / 10;
      msg.pitch = 1;
      msg.text = text;


      speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

    })
  }
});
```

Comment: any chance for a live example? (btw. `msg.rate = 10 / 10;` is the same as `msg.rate = 1` is the same as `(nothing)`, as it's 1 by default)